# how to get the absolute path to the root folder

Tags: python

This is my current folder structure, and i need to get the absolute path to the root folder

```
.
└── root/
    ├── api.py
    └── programexecutablefolder/
        └── mainentry.py
```

The program has to start at mainentry.py, however I need to get the path of the root folder from api.py (though the entry to api.py is through mainentry.py)

Also `os.getcwd()` doesn't work as it will get the directory of mainentry.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modules (typically) have an attribute named `__file__` that contains the name of the file the module was loaded from, so you should be able to do something along the lines of:

```
os.path.dirname(api.__file__)
```

(BTW: `os.getcwd()` is *not* guaranteed to give you the directory of mainentry.py unless that's the directory you're in when you start your script.)

Comment: Slight adjustment: `os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath( __file__ ))` Since the call was from the file api.py itself.